# Why are comments now disabled on "first posts" reviews?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed

As the title asks... I'm doing my normal reviews and the one hing I do on almost every "first post from a new user" is welcome them to the site and put suggested links to help them learn the ropes.  See [Why are some people reviewing new posts and not directing them to the meta and help pages?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2144/why-are-some-people-reviewing-new-posts-and-not-directing-them-to-the-meta-and-h)

I can no longer post comments...  At the bottom of the post being reviewed, it says:

> comments disabled on deleted / locked posts / reviews

Why did this change and what's the reasoning? Isn't this counter-productive?

Comment: I just came to ask the same thing.

Comment: I equally thought it ridiculous that you cannot comment vote on the close review tab. I actually find it stupid that any of the normal functions would be limited when using the review tab.

Comment: We should broach this on meta.stackoverflow.  I completely concur that disabling comments is a *bad* thing during reviews!

Comment: I can only assume that somebody doesn't like the "Welcome to C.SE!" or the guidance we give people - but both are *good* things!

Comment: So, here's the post to Meta.SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198951/why-are-comments-now-disabled-on-first-posts-reviews  Guess we'll all find out together!

Answer (score 1):

Per the answer on @affable's meta.so question, this appears to be a bug that will be fixed soon.

Comment: Aaaaand it's now fixed!