# Quality issues, or am I out of touch?

Tags: discussion

I've seen [this](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/680/can-we-reverse-the-trend-on-low-quality-posts) question, but that's mighty old now.

I admit I don't come here very often any more, but some of the stuff I've seen recently doesn't really encourage me. Admittedly, maybe my sampling method is not very good, but just looking at [this one question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/16452), I see unchallenged (and undownvoted) 'woo' (to use a term from Skeptics). And I don't mean that it's unscientific, but un- or a-biblical (or even semantically/etymologically/logically unfounded).

Exhibit A:

> For instance the fact that your and my iPad or other tablet breaks is
>   the devils fault. We contribute to the fall of the ipad sometimes but
>   if the devil was completely and totally removed and all his previous
>   influences dissolved you could let go of the iPad and the spiritual
>   forces of life in Christ Jesus would over ride the force of gravity
>   until you grabbed it again.

Exhibit B:

> Spirit means attitude, so Devil means an evil spirit(attitude). We can
>   see that the attitude of one that has fallen out of peace is
>   considered an evil attitude. Diablos means devil, and a demon is a
>   characteristic of the attitude.
>
> Therefore the demon can be categorized into three categories: Angry,
>   Depressed, or Anxious.

**Important**: I'm not calling out the people who posted these answers or 'naming and shaming', I'm just wondering why the community doesn't react more.

Is there anyone here?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking? If you don't like the answers, downvote them.

Comment: @curiousdannii, maybe you're right, I should just use my downvotes more. I'm just surprised that nobody else seems to be doing so.

Comment: Well you've got three options: upvote, do nothing, or downvote. Downvoting costs you rep, so maybe some people don't think the answers are that bad.

Comment: @curiousdannii, maybe there just aren't that many people reading them. Some answers are *very* long...

Comment: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/28242/6071 is a recent question which is just bad all round. The question is long and badly defined, asking multiple questions and multiple perspectives. And it attracts long confusing answers that may not even answer the question, but are just vaguely on-topic. I think I agree with @waxeagle below that we just need more active 3k close voters. I'd like to be one..  but it takes time!

Comment: @curiousdannii, yes I saw that yesterday. Questions like that are terrible because the sheer length and doubtful quality makes it difficult to find the motivation to read the whole thing 'just to be sure' before downvoting. And that particular user does come across as more pontificating than seeking...

Answer (score 8):

I tend to agree that there's a quality issue again.  In questions ***and*** answers.  And it's extremely disheartening.

Having watched the downward spiral, it appeared to begin a while back when there was finally enough of a push-back against the so-called "Truth Question ban" that people, even experienced users, started letting "truthy" questions stand, and answered them, rather than voting to close.  When "truthy" questions are posed, only "truthy" answers are possible.

I've been largely silent these days because I got sick of being the jerk that stood fast in my unpopular position that such questions should be discouraged, and that the ban was a good thing. I'm not sure I want to continue to participate at all.  I keep hoping the community will recover.  I'm hesitant to even post this answer, but reading your question, a part of me is saying "Thank goodness, at least one other person sees it!"  So that gives me hope, and I thank you for that, and since I have hope, and maybe it's not a fruitless battle, I'll put in a thought for the community to consider.

Honestly, I think the quality of the questions and answers on this site is going down the exact path that people like Richard, Caleb, WaxEagle, El'endia Starman, Mason Wheeler, and countless other people that helped this site graduate from Beta fought so hard to avoid.

The only real hope I see for this site to not degenerate into the "I'm right, you're a heretic" mentality that "Christian forums" always tend to devolve into is to get back to basics.  Realize that [this site is supposed to be different](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/what-christianity-stackexchange-is-and-more-importantly-what-it-isnt), and [help newcomers understand it](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3269/why-not-have-new-members-go-through-a-general-introduction-page), and practice [constant vigilance](http://freedomkeys.com/vigil.htm) in enforcing and sticking to the guidlenes that helps this site make it past beta in the first place.

I encourage every one who actually cares about this site to see Affable Geek's excellent post:  "[How we are different than other sites?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)".  Study it. Follow the links.  Understand that this site was ***meant*** to be different, and then join the side that wants to ***keep*** it different, as opposed to the side that wants to be just like every other free-for-all, infighting, bickering, prone-to-argument "Christian" forum out there.  Be different, be better,  and stand up for something different and better.

Comment: David, I must admit to being more sympathetic to 'truthy' questions than you sound. In theory. However, in practice I don't (currently) like the results. This leads me to the following thought: maybe the 'battle' should be fought less along the lines of "truthy questions are bad", and more along the lines of "truthy questions are wonderful, we love them, but here's why it is totally impossible to not degenerate into a rubbish dump if we allow them". Failing that, I think I'm just going to go on a downvoting spree :)

Comment: @Benjol -  For the record, I LOVE "Truthy" questions ***in person, in the real world***, but you nailed it.   I truly believe, based on experience, and watching the history of this site, that it is totally impossible to not degenerate into a rubbish dump if we allow them.

Comment: @Benjol you've nailed it. What we *really* need is a group of active 3k close voters. It's hard for the mods to single vote close a lot of stuff, and there are only 4 of us. Site moderation *has* to be a community effort or it will not work.