# Why if this is a discussion forum for Christianity are Christianity Q's closed as off topic?

Tags: discussion

Thread Example: If flesh & blood cannot inherit the kingdom of God how did the Lord Jesus show His “hands and feet” after the resurrection?
[If flesh & blood cannot inherit the kingdom of God how did the Lord Jesus show His "hands and feet" after the resurrection?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/26782/if-flesh-blood-cannot-inherit-the-kingdom-of-god-how-did-the-lord-jesus-show-h?newreg=62da8412277e4f11abbc7bf0b5cbfd7b)

Reason for that thread close? Answers are subjective? 
The entire Bible could be labeled thus.

Comment: Did you visit the link in the explanation of why it was closed? [We can't handle the truth](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3527/20)

Comment: The LDS have a different perspective than any of the answers (seem to have) to the referenced question

Comment: ***None*** of the Stack Exchange sites are discussion forums. They're all Q&A sites. To ask an objective question on this site, the subject must be narrowed down to a specific faith tradition so that there can be a definite answer. This site is about discovering the beliefs of existing Christian groups, not inventing new beliefs or arguing about which tradition is best.

Comment: @4castle Why don't you post this comment as an *answer*? That way it will be visible -- a wee shame for 9 UV's (as I type) to be "invisible" to the system.....

Comment: @Dɑvïd I'm more accustomed to using Meta on Stack Overflow. I guess I thought using comments was commonplace.

Comment: Because it isn't a discussion forum.

Comment: I'm with @4castle on this one.  It took me a while to get used to the idea that, as useful as a "what does everyone believe?" question may be, they're too often overshadowed by what KorvinStarmast calls the "2,000 year old shouting match."  However, it appears to me if WelshRabbit was willing to identify a specific tradition to encompass his question, it could be re-opened.  Given a specific context, it appears a completely answerable question to me.

Answer (score 5):

Simply put, it's because *not all "Christians" agree* on the answer to this question.

This site's definition of "Christian" is very broad – any group that claims to be Christian is, for our purposes, "Christian."  There are thousands and thousands of such groups, and they very frequently disagree, particularly in the interpretation of Bible verses like these.

In order for a question like this to be "on topic" for our site, it would need to specify *whose views are desired*.  That is, it could ask for the views of Mormons, or Reformed theologians, or Roman Catholicism.  In some cases, it might be possible to ask for an "overview" of the views of various traditions.

Without specifying a tradition, this is a "[truth question](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3527/21576)," which we have found lead to discussion and debate, not answers.  This site is for Q&A, whereas a question like this (as currently written) might be better suited for a discussion forum.

Answer (score 4):

See [Real Questions have answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/), which applies as a guideline for pretty much all StackExchange sites.

- If you want to discuss something, you go to a discussion forum.
- If you want an answer to a question, you go to a StackExchange site.

This is why questions that are open ended and open to interpretation are closed.

There's also a ton of info in the [frequently asked questions](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) on Meta that answer this in a dozen or so other ways.

Comment: While it's true that a wealth of information is on the FAQ, the assumption that a new user should simply go there and figure it out is naive at best, draconian at worst.  New users post questions that are closed so often that it suggests our path into and through the question-asking process is not well enough defined for non-webpage-wanderers.

Comment: @JBH - I agree. When I was more active on the site, I tried to do something about that.  There's some disagreement on whether or not it was helpful.  See [Are “Welcome to Christianity SE” comments helpful?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3868/) and [Why not have new members go through a general introduction page?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3269/).