# Why was my answer to *christian-and-sin* deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-answer

As I understand the question; it is asking why a Christian should have concern about sinning since Jesus has already paid for our sins. My answer was directed to that particular question, and to me covered the reasons a Christian should care? If I have misunderstood or misstated something I feel that I deserve an explanation as to the particular wrong. Please advise me of what is unacceptable about my answer. I am not trying to be contentious, or questioning the deletion, it is only that I do not understand what is wrong.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the question?

Comment: If a question is off topic, you see if [Biblical Hermeneutics StackExchange](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/) can answer it. Otherwise you can ask it on [Bible Wiki](http://bible.wikia.com/wiki/Board:Bible_Questions).

Answer (score 7):

The rationale provided in David's and Caleb's answers to your meta question from a few years ago applies here as well: [What is wrong with answering general questions Biblicaly?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4117/21576)

I won't rehash the entire argument, but in my judgment this question, [Christian and Sin](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/56340/21576), is clearly off-topic.  It asks a truth question and does not ask for a specific tradition's viewpoint.  Such questions should not be answered, and should definitely not be answered with personal exegesis.

Therefore, when I closed the question, I also deleted the answers.  Allowing the answers to remain would encourage people to hurry up and answer off-topic questions before they are closed, which is exactly what we do not want.  If you answer an off-topic question, it's thus important to recognize that there is a strong chance that your answer will be deleted.

Please reread David's and Caleb's answers to the question linked above.  And please: *do not answer off-topic questions, particularly with personal exegesis*.  If you do, it should not surprise you when it is deleted.

Of course, deletion is not necessarily permanent.  If the question is edited to be on-topic, and if you edit your answer to directly answer what the updated question asks, please flag it so that a moderator can review it for undeletion.